# Beginner's apache mod_rewrite assistance with .htaccess configuration

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

noob when it comes to *.htaccess*.

I need a mod_rewrite of a URL. URL example is as shown:

```
http://example.com/folder/script.php?location=UK&Name=Fred
```

I want it to transform to:

```
http://example.com/folder/UK/Fred
```

Comment: In addition to the answers below, I've found this site useful for rewrite rule checking: http://civilolydnad.se/projects/rewriterule/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} location=([^&]+)&Name=(.+)
RewriteRule ^/folder/script.php$ http://website.com/folder/%1/%2? [R]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1/script.php?location=$2&Name=$3
```

This will rewrite requests to `/<folder>/<location>/<Name>` internally to `/<folder>/script.php?location=<location>&Name=<Name>`.